# Is it possible to have a manual approval in Jenkins for a job?

Tags: jenkins, github

I was wondering if it is possible to have a manual approval before a job is started. Also, can this be done for a freestyle job?

So, the flow which I am thinking is -

1. Jenkins Webhook received a `push` event basically starting the job.
2. An approval email is sent out to the approver for further execution.
3. The approver approves the execution and then the job starts proceeding ahead...

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in a freestyle with the plugins available (IMHO). But it can be with a `DSL` based pipeline using the `input` step right before your main stages are invoked.

Comment: I created a separate job, added restrictions on it and it can only be triggered after approval for another ones build :P .